# How to remove a css file from an already-overridden definition?

Tags: theming, 10

I want to create a custom theme and remove a css file from diretory **themes/stable/css/filter.caption.css** from Stable theme. I found this file in **stable.info.yml**

```
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
    css:
      component:
          css/filter.caption.css: css/filter/filter.caption.css
```

From **my_custom.info.yml**

```
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
    css:
      component:
        css/filter.caption.css: false
```

or

```
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
    css:
      component:
        css/filter/filter.caption.css: false
```

I tried that way but it is not work to remove a css file **themes/statble/css/filter.caption.css**.

Comment: This seems to have been asked a few times here in the past.

Comment: How can I do that when a css file defined in info.yml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override or disable a parent theme's CSS file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182528/how-can-i-override-or-disable-a-parent-themes-css-file)

Comment: That link does not answer my question. I want to remove a css file from stable theme but that file is curently override from another css file.

Comment: This may be an open bug in Drupal, but there are workarounds: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2642122

Comment: Thank you @cilefen for helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **stable.info.yml** we have

```
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
     css:
       component:
         css/filter.caption.css: css/filter/filter.caption.css
```

So **my_theme.info.yml** to disable it could be:

```
libraries-override:
  filter/caption:
    css:
      component:
        /themes/contrib/stable/css/filter/filter.caption.css: false
```

A bug in libraries-override makes it difficult to override a library or library asset that has already been overridden. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2642122#comment-11830072 for more information.

Comment: In case anyone looking at this answer is using core/themes/stable9 instead of themes/contrib/stable, you would need to include this instead after component including the leading slash: /core/themes/stable9/css/...